# no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::string () const" to "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>"

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to design a class "Book" which has members for a book's serial number, author, title, etc. I have put all these members in private and decided to make public functions to return these data values to the user without allowing any access to modifying these values.
Code is given as follow:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

class Date 
{
public:
    //...
private:
    int y, m, d;
};

class Book 
{
public:
    string ISBN() const { return ISBN; }
    string title() const { return title; }
    string author() const { return author; }
    Date copyright_date() const { return copyright_date; }
    bool availability() { return availability; }
    
    void check_out();

private:
    string ISBN;                         
    string title;
    string author;
    Date copyright_date;
    bool availability;
};
```

I'm currently getting this error from this code,

> E0415 no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::string ()
> const" to "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits,
> std::allocator>"

Please ignore the header file as it has no part in this problem. It's  a custom header which allows access to multiple standard library functions and user-defined functions at once.

Comment: You can't have the same name for a function and a member variable. You sure you didn't get any earlier errors that looked like `error: ‘std::__cxx11::string Book::ISBN’ conflicts with a previous declaration string ISBN;` or `error C2365: 'Book::ISBN': redefinition; previous definition was 'member function'`?

Comment: You'd be surprised how many questions we get that ARE the fault of that header.

Comment: @user4581301 not this one though :)